# I am trying to use a method in order to find which numbers in the array are greater than 20 and return a percentage

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, math

This is what I have written so far I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
public double findPercentageGreaterThanTwenty(int[] intArray) {
    double average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        sum = i;
        if (intArray[i] > 20) {
            average = (average + intArray[i]) / sum;
        }
    }
    return average;
}
```

Comment: What does the average have to do with it?

Comment: It was just a place holder word I used in this method

Answer (score 5):

Average has nothing to do with. Simply increment the count when a number larger than 20 occurs.

```
public double findPercentageGreaterThanTwenty(int[] intArray) {
    double count=0;
    for (int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        if (intArray[i] > 20) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count / intArray.length * 100; // returns the result in %
}
```

The expression `count / intArray.length` returns value between `0` (that's 0%) and `1` (that's 100%). Multiply it by 100 gives you the percentage result.

---

Alternatively for others there's the Java 8 solution using Stream-API. However I recommend you the first solution to learn the fundamentals at all :)

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 5, 9, 12, 23, 25, 31, 33, 48};
long count = Arrays.stream(array).filter(n -> n > 20).count();
System.out.println(count / array.length * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The average has nothing to do with the percentage of numbers above twenty. All you need to do is count them and divide that number by the total number of elements in the array:

```
public double findPercentageGreaterThanTwenty(int[] intArray) {
    int above20 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        ++above20;
    }
    return ((double) above20) / intArrary.length;
}
```

Note that this will return a double between 0 and 1. If you want a percentage between 0 and 100, just multiply it by 100.